# Xamarin, No valid Provisioning Profiles found after updating Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I recently updated Xcode to version 8.3.2 and it had a knock-on effect to my Xamarin iOS project where it now cannot find any valid provisioning profiles.

I've tried going through the guide here several times but that doesn't seem to do anything:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/

I've tried removing all the profiles from ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ and downloading just the one I want from the Apple website.

I've tried revoking all certificates and recreating.

I've tried creating a new project in Xcode with the same bundle identifier to auto-generate the certificates and profiles needed.

I'm on versions:

- Visual Studio for Mac preview 8 (7.0 build 2845)
- Xamarin.iOS 10.10.0.11
- Apple Developer Tools 8.3.2 (12175)
- Mac OS X 10.12.4

[image: iOS Bundle Signing]
[image: No Provisioning Profile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

1) In Xcode, Goto --> Build --> clean all targets.

2) In "Groups & Files" -->Target --> expand it --> right click your app and select Clean "your app"

3) Goto->Window-->Organizer

4) In the Devices tab on the left, select your iphone

5) In the Provisioning section of the selected iphone delete all the current profiles (if any)

6) Unplug your iPhone and replug it in.

7) Goto->Window-->Organizer-->right click your iPhone -->Add device to provisioning portal

8) Now make sure you have selected the appropriate code signing identity in edit project settings -> build --> code signing

Build and run. Good luck!

Comment: Did what parts I could as this isn't an Xcode project but didn't seem to affect anything. One thing I did notice though was that I had no provisioning profiles on my Mac only on my iPhone, should there be any?

Comment: yes in your iphone provisional profile exist. if you have build project with latest provisional profile.

Comment: Not an answer for a Xamarin project although a full clean in Xamarin worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create the iOS Distribution signing identity. This can be found at Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > View Details